# テキスト入力時の入力支援を止めたい

Tags: 機能の要求

質問の入力フォームの中でCtrl+bを押すと`**強調太文字**`と入力されてます。
場合によって不便なことがあるので、入力されないようする良い方法はないでしょうか？

Comment: 文字を選択してからCtrl-Bを押すと、選択されたテキストが`**`に囲むだけですが、やっぱり、日本人が括弧を入力するとき、とりあえず両方を入れてからテキストを入力しますよね。確認のため、Ctrl-Bを押せば、`****`だけを要求していますかね？

Comment: 私はEmacsユーザなのでカーソルをひとつ戻そうとしてCtrl+bをおしてしまいます。そうすると意図せずに入力されてしまうのです。

自分だけならブラウザのユーザスクリプトなので対処できそうですが、別の理由で似たような問題が起こる場合もあるので、入力支援を無効にしたりできたら良いと思ったという意図です。

Comment: 経験的にこれはユーザースクリプト対応がベストだと思います。これを日本語版に変えると不親切と思うユーザーも現れるし、当社の方針はできるだけオプションを少なくしたいとのことです。もちろん、開発者にこのような要求は他のサイトにあるかないかとかを聞きますが、とりあえずユーザースクリプトを作って、メタの投稿で共有したらどうですか？もしくは英語ですが、[Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/)もあります。そこで登録すればできると思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack Exchange全体のメタに同じ要望があり、私はそこに投稿されているChrome拡張で無効化しています:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123256/157841

コードの二重管理を避けるため、ここには引用しませんが、ブックマークレット、ユーザースクリプト、Chrome拡張の3つが回答に含まれています。

Chrome拡張は以下の手順でインストールできます:

1. どこかにディレクトリを掘り、回答にある2つのファイルを作る

   - manifest.json
   - contentscript.js
   - 1.5 manifest.json の `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/*` を `http://*.stackoverflow.com/*` に変える
2. chrome://extensions/ を開く
3. 開発者モードを有効にする
4. <kbd>Load unpacked extension....</kbd>ボタンをクリック
5. ステップ 1 で作ったディレクトリを選択